# If operator inside method doesn't return right value

Tags: java

```
public class EX02 {

public static int currentDay;
public static String result;

/**
 * Constant.
 * Every 3 days, feed worms.
 */
public static final int WORM_FEEDING_DAY = 3;

/**
 * Constant.
 * Every 5 days, bathe in sand.
 */
public static final int BATHING_DAY = 5;

/**
 * Constant.
 * Total number of days for which instructions are needed.
 */
public static final int NUMBER_OF_DAYS = 30;

/**
 * Entry point of the program.
 * @param args Arguments from command line.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    getInstructionForCurrentDay(currentDay);
    // call and print getInstructionForCurrentDay inside a loop here
    for (currentDay = 1; currentDay < NUMBER_OF_DAYS +1; currentDay++) {
        currentDay = 30 - (NUMBER_OF_DAYS - currentDay);

        System.out.println("DAY " + currentDay + result);
    }


    System.out.println("Can't fly back in time");

}



/**
 * Return instruction for given day.
 * @param currentDay number of day to print instructions for.
 */
public static String getInstructionForCurrentDay(int currentDay) {

    if (currentDay % 3 == 0){
        result = ":feed worms";
    }
    else if (currentDay % 5 == 0){
        result = ":time to bath";
    }
    else if (currentDay % 5 == 0 && currentDay % 3 ==0  ){
        result = ":glide";
    }
    else if (currentDay % 3 !=0 || currentDay % 5 != 0) {
        result = ":give fruit and water";
    }

    return result;
}
}
```

Problem is that 'getInstructionForCurrentDay(int currentDay)' doesn't return wanted value inside Main method. What did I do wrong?

Comment: `String str = getInstructionForCurrentDay(currentDay);`

Comment: What is `result`? It is not declared in the code sample...

Comment: @fge: It is - the code is just badly formatted :(

Answer (score 2):

Your

```
if (currentDay % 5 == 0 && currentDay % 3 ==0  )
```

condition should come first, otherwise it can never be reached.

Beside that, you should assign the result of `getInstructionForCurrentDay(currentDay);` to some variable if you want the caller of that method to use it, and you should call `getInstructionForCurrentDay(currentDay)` inside the loop, since `currentDay` is only assigned inside the loop.

```
// call and print getInstructionForCurrentDay inside a loop here
for (currentDay = 1; currentDay < NUMBER_OF_DAYS +1; currentDay++) {
    currentDay = 30 - (NUMBER_OF_DAYS - currentDay);
    result = getInstructionForCurrentDay(currentDay);
    System.out.println("DAY " + currentDay + result);
}

...

public static String getInstructionForCurrentDay(int currentDay) {

    if (currentDay % 5 == 0 && currentDay % 3 ==0  ){
        result = ":glide";
    }
     else if (currentDay % 3 == 0){
        result = ":feed worms";
    }
    else if (currentDay % 5 == 0){
        result = ":time to bath";
    }
    else {
        result = ":give fruit and water";
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `currentDay` into your method before it is instantiated, so you are literally passing `0` into it.

Therefore, all of your if statement conditions are never met, so `result` is also never given a value and thus not returning what you want.

Instead, I believe you wanted to do this:

```
for (currentDay = 1; currentDay < NUMBER_OF_DAYS +1; currentDay++)   
{        
    getInstructionForCurrentDay(currentDay);
    System.out.println("DAY " + currentDay + result);
    currentDay = 30 - (NUMBER_OF_DAYS - currentDay);
}
```

Comment: `currentDay` just contains a zero value, not nothing.

Comment: Yes, sorry, overlooked the fact that an integer cannot be null and gets defaulted to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Thank YOU, I solved it this way:

```
public class EX02 {
/**
 * Constant. Every 3 days, feed worms.
 */
public static final int WORM_FEEDING_DAY = 3;
/**
 * Constant. Every 5 days, bathe in sand.
 */
public static final int BATHING_DAY = 5;
/**
 * Constant. Total number of days for which instructions are needed.
 */
public static final int NUMBER_OF_DAYS = 30;
/**
 * Entry point of the program.
 *
 * @param args
 *            Arguments from command line.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // call and print getInstructionForCurrentDay inside a loop here
    if (NUMBER_OF_DAYS < 1) {
        System.out.println("Can't fly back in time");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    for (int currentDay = 1; currentDay <= NUMBER_OF_DAYS; currentDay++) {
        System.out.println("Day " + currentDay + ": "
                + getInstructionForCurrentDay(currentDay));
    }
}
/**
 * Return instruction for given day.
 *
 * @param currentDay
 *            number of day to print instructions for.
 */
 public static String getInstructionForCurrentDay(int currentDay) {
    String result = "";
    if (currentDay % WORM_FEEDING_DAY == 0 && currentDay % BATHING_DAY == 0)
        result = "glide in wind";
    else if (currentDay % WORM_FEEDING_DAY == 0)
        result = "feed worms";
    else if (currentDay % BATHING_DAY == 0)
        result = "bathe in sand";
    else
        return "give fruit and water";
    return result;
}
```

}